# Windows XP cannot read DVD burned on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, dvd, disc

**The story** :
I have burned a DVD disc on Ubuntu using Brasero. When file burning was complete, I canceled the burning of checksum to DVD. Then I put that DVD on Windows XP (SP3) and copied all the files from DVD to the hard drive (no errors when copying). When that was done I discovered that all copied files are not readable. What is more, all the files on that DVD also shown to be not readable, even though all file names, directories were in their place.

**What I found out?**
Windows detect that the disc is in CDFS (CD-ROM File System).
Disc is clean as new, have no scratches.
All files while opened in Notepad++ look like "NULNULNULNULNUL" in one line.
The size of files is normal.
Other discs that are recognized as CDFS can be read with no problems.

**What I tried?**
Starting CDFS service in Windows registry. Result - a new device in Windows Device Manager (JUBS JGH2ZCT SCSI CdRom Device).
Removing my CD/DVD device from Device Manager. Result - Windows restarted the system and reinstalled the driver.

So... how to read the DVD, when I have no access to any other PC, any other OS?

Comment: Have you successfully previously burned a readable cd on Ubuntu? Or is this a first time deal? And why did you cancel part of the process? Maybe that had something to do with it? My gut instinct would say it's a bad burn, look at ubuntu...

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a CD/DVD data recovery tool like isobuster

Comment: I'm going to try it, but I don't get why Windows think that it's all ok with the dvd. It displays file names, allows copying, opening them with no errors. The problem that the data is wrong (NULNULNUL?)

Comment: Do try it and post what happens , i have a feeling that its a burn issue . Was the dvd working find in ur ubuntu system ?

Comment: I haven't tryed opening the dvd in any other pc. I was burning it in a hurry - that's why i cancelled the burning of checksum.

Comment: Tryed the Isobuster - it also thinks that it's everything ok with the dvd.